# Does picard markduplicate toggle PCR duplicate samflag

Tags: bioinformatics, samtools, picard

I have a RNA-seq bam file and there are few reads that are puzzling me.

According to the bam header, this bam file is sorted by coordinate, created using tophat and markduplicate step is not done. But some reads are marked for being duplicate in the samflag. What is worse is when I run picard markduplicate, these reads' pcr duplicate flag is toggled, marking them not a duplicate. Also I manually found the duplicate of this read (identical reads with same start positions and mates start position) so initial marking looks true.
So my questions are: 
Any idea why would this happen?
Does Tophat mark reads for being duplicate? ( I don't think so)
And does picard markduplicate will toggle if the reads are already marked for being duplicate?

Here is how the read looks before and after mark duplicate step.
Before:
C0RTF   1187  17  7579880 255  61M10754N40M  =  7579927 10902   CTC... 
0UNP1   163   17  7579880 255  61M10754N40M  =  7579927 10902   CTC... 

After Markduplicate
C0RTF   163   17  7579880 255  61M10754N40M  =  7579927 10902   CTC... 
0UNP1   163   17  7579880 255  61M10754N40M  =  7579927 10902   CTC...

Thanks

Comment: This question might be better suited for https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com?

Comment: Thanks, I just asked there too.